# Having a custom ListView with different options to choose from

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently building a ListView VERY similiar to the standard alarm clock app that comes with any android phone today. In the app they have a ListView that has different views for each row.

For example:

http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/listviewwithmultiplechoice.png

and

http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/attachments/android-development-answers-tutorials-code-snippets/360d1234754310-add-edittext-backgroundtxt-child-expandable-list-screencap1.png

I would like for both of the options to use checkboxes and the expandable View on the same ListView. I've tried looking for tutorials but none have really helped.

In my code, I'm looking to have the view be a combination of the expandable list View and multiple choice view. 
Whats the best way to do something like this?
Here is my code currently.

```
public class AlarmList extends ListActivity {
    AlarmListItem[] items = {
            new AlarmListItem("Turn On Alarm", Alerts.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Time", Person.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Time", MTSU_Android.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Sound", Person.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Vibrate", Alerts.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Repeat", Alerts.class),
            new AlarmListItem("Volume", MTSU_Android.class),
            new AlarmListItem("BackupAlarm", Person.class)};

            @Override
            public void onCreate (Bundle icicle)
            {
                super.onCreate(icicle);
                setContentView(R.layout.main3);
                //ListView list1 = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01));
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<AlarmListItem>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id )
            {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                final Intent intent = new Intent(this, items[position].getActivity());
                startActivityForResult(intent, position);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend ListAdapter and override [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).  Use getItem using the passed position to obtain the object and then return a view suitable for the object passed.

If the view depends on the class of object, then test using instanceof.

Comment: So you're saying instead of ListActivity I need to extend ListAdapter?
And then Once I get the object with getitem, do I need to create several new xml files for each view? such as: temp1.xml, temp2.xml, temp3.xml,
Then inflate each of them for a different View? like...
`getItem(position);
layoutInflater myInflater;
View v = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.temp1);
View v1 = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.temp2);`
So forth...?

Comment: Keep your ListActivity, but create a custom ListAdapter (extend, for example, ArrayAdapter<Object>.  Use it by calling setListAdapter(yourCustomListAdapter).

Yes, do inflate a different view everytime getView is called.  Make sure the passed view is not null and is not of the type you wish to inflate before you inflate a new one everything - for efficiency.